# Javascript object literal passing properties to jquery plugin options

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

This is one of those problems that's been bothering me for a while but I always just worked around it without truly figuring out a proper solution... Apologies if it has been answered before but I couldn't find an answer. If at all possible I'd like to avoid refactoring the object literal pattern.

In the following example, I can't access NS.something and I'm not sure why...

```
var NS = {
    something : 'abc',

    init : function(){
        NS.doSomething();
    },

    doSomething : function(){
        $('.elements').jqueryPlugin({
            pluginParameters: {
                NS.something : 'xyz';
            }
        })
    }
};

NS.init();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define an object literal with a variable key, you have to assign it after definition with `[]` notation.

```
doSomething : function(){
    var pluginParameters = {};
    pluginParameters[NS.property] = 'xyz';
    $('.elements').jqueryPlugin({
        pluginParameters: pluginParameters
    })
}
```

Comment: great stuff thanks a lot :-) After seeing this work I was expecting to be able to created nested objects in the same way like `pluginParameters[NS.property][blah] = 'xyz';` but that didn't seem to work. Instead I'm using `pluginParameters[NS.property] = {blah:'xyz'};` which works ok.

Comment: @JamesSmith `pluginParameters[NS.property] = {}; pluginParameters[NS.property][blah] = 'xyz';`